# Is it possible to use programmatic IAP authentication with Kubernetes Gateway API in GKE?

Tags: api, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gateway

GKE Ingress is integrated with IAP: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-kubernetes-howto The problem we have is that we need header based routing, which is not supported. Kubernetes Gateway API supports header based routing but I haven't seen any documentation on how to integrate it with IAP. The client will also be a machine (no user involved) so we would need to authenticate from a service account. Thanks in advance!

Comment: We have been there, it is not supported unfortunately at the moment.